# MySQL testcontainers test can't connect to JDBC using default credentials

Tags: mysql, docker, testcontainers

I'm trying to initialize MySQL test-container using Kotlin and Gradle(7.4.2),
container configuration logic listed below:

```
class MySQL internal constructor(
    dockerImageName: DockerImageName
) : MySQLContainer<MySQL?>(dockerImageName), ConfigurableContainer {

    ...
    ... 

    companion object {
        val instance: MySQL?
        const val name = "failed-mysql"
        const val isStateful = true

        init {
            val dockerImage = "mysql:8.0.28"

            instance = ContainerBuilder.createContainer(name) {
                MySQL(DockerImageName.parse(dockerImage).asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mysql"))
                    .withUsername("root")
                    ?.withPassword("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ContainerBuilder::createContainer logic:

```
fun <T : GenericContainer<*>?> createContainer(name: String, builder: Supplier<T?>?): T? {
    log.info("Initializing $name")

    return builder?.get()!!.apply {
        this.withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(startupTimeoutSeconds.toLong()))
        this.withNetworkAliases(name)
        this.withExtraHost("host.docker.internal", "host-gateway")

        if (isLongLive) {
            this.withReuse(true)
            this.withCreateContainerCmdModifier { cmd: CreateContainerCmd ->
                cmd.withName(name)
                cmd.hostConfig?.apply {
                   withRestartPolicy(RestartPolicy.unlessStoppedRestart())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The container is created successfully, the root user without a password also exists, manually I can connect without any problems, but in the console inside testcontainers internals it trying to connect via jdbc to my database, but without success (and after ~200 attempts I crash with a timeout):

```
2022-05-24 14:03:40 DEBUG Trying to create JDBC connection using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true with properties: {password=, user=root}
```

I assumed that the problem was with the user сredentials, but I can connect mannualy with no problems, also if I'm trying to reconfugure it with PostgreSQL container - have no issues as well.

Additional information:

1. docker version: `20.10.13, build a224086`
2. mysql docker image: `mysql:8.0.28`
3. gradle dependencies:

   ```
   // test-containers
   api(platform("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.16.3"))
   api("org.testcontainers:mysql")

   // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
   implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28")
   ```

Comment: What happens if you use a non-empty password?

Comment: same, even if I'm trying another user (test:test by default)

Comment: Just to be sure, please upgrade to the latest Testcontainers version `1.17.2`.  I see we are internally running tests against `mysql:8.0.24` in Testcontainers, so this should generally work. Can you please share a minimal reproducer image? It might also be better to create an issue at Testcontainers directly.

Comment: I meant reproducer repo, sorry.

Comment: Hey @KevinWittek, sorry for pending, I've switched to 5.7 mysql and it works finally fine :) not a best solution, but covers my case, thanks for trying to help

Comment: Newer `mqsql` images changed defaults around SSL connections, which might be related. However, I can confirm that Testcontainers generally works with `mysql:8.0.28`, I just tried it out.